# Python3 Singly Linked List achievement issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have write a simple single linked list through Python3, But the search function in the class not performed properly . 
I think the other function are OK.

```
class Node():
    """节点"""
    def __init__(self, elem):
        self.elem = elem
        self.next = None  #initialed the next node as None

class SingleLinkList():
    """single linked list"""
    def __init__(self, node=None):
        self.__head = node

    def travel(self):
        '''traversing the linked list'''
        cur = self.__head
        while cur != None:
            print(cur.elem, end = ' ')
            cur = cur.next
        print('\n')

    def add(self, item):
        '''Add elements to the list header'''
        node = Node(item)
        node.next = self.__head
        self.__head = node

    def search(self, item):
        '''Verify node existence'''
        cur = self.__head
        while not cur:
            if cur.elem == item:
                return True
            else:
                cur = cur.next
        return False

l1 = SingleLinkList()
l1.add(2)
l1.add(3)
l1.travel()
print(l1.search(2))

[~]$ python3 temp.py
3 2
False
```

Obviously, when search int `2`, it should contained in the list , So the output should be `True` other than `False`. Could you please help me figured it out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to make a slight change to `search` method.

This simply means that, until the `cur` doesn't point to `None`, keep looping. When the variable `cur` is initialized for the first time, it points to the first element, which is not None. If you try to loop using the condition `while not cur`, the condition evaluates to false, in the first iteration itself, and it will `return False` under all circumstances.

```
def search(self, item):
    '''Verify node existence'''
    cur = self.__head
    while cur:
        if cur.elem == item:
            return True
        cur = cur.next
    return False
```